# Rotate Image Clockwise using LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can we rotate a Image Clockwise using LibGDX? what i am looking is when a image is loaded,suppose a star, i need to rotate it from beginning of screen to end of the screen horizontally, with star rotating,how can i do that in libgdx?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you rotating a Texture, Sprite, or Image? By "rotate it from beginning of screen to end of the screen horizontally, with star rotating" do you mean you want the star to move horizontally while rotating?

Comment: @RahatAhmed : sorry, i am having a texture, yes.i need it to be rotate while move horizontally

Answer (score 10):

When you draw the Texture with your SpriteBatch, you can use one of the draw functions that includes rotation. This javadoc has all the draw functions: [SpriteBatch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html)

You can keep a variable for position and rotation, and increase the rotation and x component of the position each time you render to make it rotate while moving horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

Libgdx gives you more then one way to do that:
You can use `Scene2D` and add an `Image` to your `Stage`. `Image` is a subclass of `Actor`, so you can add `Action`s to it:

```
Image myImage = new Image(myTexture);
myImage.addAction(Actions.parallel(Actions.moveTo(endX, endY, duration), Actions.rotateBy(degrees, duration)));
myImage.setPosition(startX, startY);
myImage.setOrigin(sizeX/2, sizeY/2);
stage.add(myImage);
```

In `render` you can then call `stage.act()`, which updates the position, rotation, scale... of all your `Actor`s and then call `stage.draw()` which will call `draw()` for all your `Actor`s.
Image allready handles the `draw()` so you don't need to care about that anymore.

You can also do it without `scene2d`, by updating everything yourself:
You can store a `int rotationSpeed` in degrees/sec
You can store a `int moveSpeed` in units/sec (maybe pixel but i would suggest to use camera or viewport and use your own unit, which is equal on all devices)
Store the `float angle`, which is the current rotation of your `Texture`
and store a `Vector2 position`, which contains the x and y position of your `Texture`.
If you want to move in x and y direction you can also store a `Vector2 direction`, which is a normalized `Vector`, giving the percent of movement in x and y direction, but thats a different story.

Then in your `render(float delta)` you update everything:

```
angle+=delta*rotationSpeed;
angl%=360;      // Limits the angle to be <= 360
while (angle < 0)  // Unfortunally the "modulo" in java gives negative result for negativ values.
    angle+=360;
position.x+=direction.x*moveSpeed*delta;
position.y+=direction.y*movSpeed*delta;
spriteBatch.draw(yourTextureRegion, position.x, position.y, sizeX/2, sizeY/2, sizeX, sizeY, scaleX, scaleY, angle);
```

For clockwise rotation simply use a negative `rotationSpeed` or replace the `angle+=` with `angle-=`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the implementation to rotate any sprite

```
batch.draw(sprite,(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - sprite.getRegionWidth()) / 2.0f,(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - sprite.getRegionHeight()) / 2.0f,sprite.getRegionWidth()/2.0f,sprite.getRegionHeight()/2.0f, sprite.getRegionWidth(), sprite.getRegionHeight(), 1f, 1f,count, false);

if(count < 0.0f)
count = 360.0f;
else
count --;
```

Initially set counter to

```
private float count =360.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Scene2D actions. I have an example here with asteroid-type thing falling down the screen and rotating.

http://www.netthreads.co.uk/2012/02/09/libgdx-scene2d-demo-with-scene-transitions/

Answer (score 1):

To rotate anticlockwise and horizontally..
create a textureRegion
then

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(textureRegion, 0, 0, 128, 128);
sprite.setPosition(++mX, 0);
angle++;
sprite.setRotation(angle);
sprite.draw(batcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

So the following sample worked for me (infinite rotation)

**Method 1: (recommended)**

```
loadingActor.addAction(Actions.repeat(RepeatAction.FOREVER, Actions.rotateBy(360, 1)));
```

**Method 2:**

```
Image loadingActor = new Image(AssetsController.getInstance().getLoading());
loadingActor.setOrigin(Align.center);
final SequenceAction infiniteRotate = Actions.sequence();
infiniteRotate.addAction(Actions.rotateTo(0 , 0f) );
infiniteRotate.addAction(Actions.rotateTo(360 , 1f) );
loadingActor.addAction(Actions.forever(infiniteRotate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it too like this:

on your create method

```
sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWitdh() /2f, sprite.getHeight() /2f);
sprite.setPosition( 0, 200 ); //200 it's a example
```

on your render(float delta)

```
sprite.setX( sprite.getX() + delta ).setRotation( sprite.getRotation() + delta );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple to rotate an actor in libgdx. First you need to set the origin:

```
img.setOrigin(getWidth/2,getHeight/2);
```

And then you can rotate clockwise and anticlockwise according to your need:

```
img.rotate(2f); or img.rotate(-2f);
```