# LibGDX - Rotate SpriteBatch on itself

Tags: rotation, libgdx, spritebatch

[image]

I would like to rotate this **SpriteBatch** on itself upon clicking on a button

```
@Override
public void render() {

    SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(gemTexture, 10, 10, 100, 100);
    batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        rotateRight();
    }
```

}

```
private void rotateRight() {
// How do I rotate it to look like 
}
```

[image]

Comment: Something similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445035/rotate-image-clockwise-using-libgdx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're drawing a Texture using a SpriteBatch. A Texture doesn't support rotation. I suggest that the [Sprite](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch#Sprite) class might be better suited for what you are trying to do. Here's a rough outline of what you might do... see the [Sprite javadoc](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) for more detail.

```
private void createGemSprite() {
    gemSprite = new Sprite(gemTexture);
    gemSprite.setPosition(10, 10);
}

@Override
public void render() {

    SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

    batch.begin();
    gemSprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        rotateRight();
    }
}

private void rotateRight() {
    gemSprite.setRotation(gemSprite.getRotation() - 90);
}
```

Comment: In case i have a gun (firing constantly at the bottom horizontal position) how can i rotate the gun and shoot the bullets at **touched** angle?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar that's really a separate question, but Camera.unproject() and Math.atan2() are a good place to start.

Comment: @RodHyde Lazy enough to write a new question ;) any way thanks.