# LibGDX creating texture from base64 PNG ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: android, textures, libgdx, slick2d, bytearrayinputstream

I just decided to make the change from Slick2D to LibGDX. However, for me to be able to port my game over to LibGDX I need help understanding how to create textures in LibGDX from my game data files.

My game data files are encrypted and the images are encoded in base64 so I can keep them all in one txt file. How do I create a LibGDX texture from a ByteArrayInputStream.

In Slick2D I converted the base64 string into a bufferedimage. But I don't want to do that for LibGDX since I may want to get it on android soon.

EDIT: I just figured it out, kind of. I did it like so:

```
   Texture bucket;
    String base64 = "base64 string too long to paste"
    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64Coder.decode(base64);
    bucket = new Texture(new Pixmap(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length));
```

However, now the image is flipped vertically... Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unlike many discussion boards, Stack Overflow is oriented around (single) questions and answers.  Please post your "EDIT" as an answer (its okay to answer your own questions).  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that.
it says:
"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: This link should help with the rotation part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445035/rotate-image-clockwise-using-libgdx

Comment: Yeah I figured I could do that but I want the texture created right side up. Will flipping the byte array be the proper way?

Comment: Solved. I created a sprite instead of a texture and flipped it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Texture bucket;
String base64 = "base64 string too long to paste"
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64Coder.decode(base64);
bucket = new Texture(new Pixmap(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length));
```

That worked for me.

It was flipped because I changed the OrthgraphicsCamera to have 0,0 at the upper left.