# 360 degree movements animated sprite Java Game Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

The majority of sprites for simple goes move up, down, left, right at 90 degree intervals, often using different sprite sheets for each direction.

However I would like to create a sprite that follows the mouse/finger input (but not on the finger, slightly slower) and rotates on an axis using relevant degrees as appropriate, so it is always following/looking at the finger, i would also like to include 1 sprite sheet for the movement of the sprite. Is there a way of rotating the sprite to get the desired affect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate Image Clockwise using LibGDX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445035/rotate-image-clockwise-using-libgdx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SpriteBatch` for rendering sprites, then you can just pass the rotation argument to the draw function:

```
draw(TextureRegion region, float x, float y, float originX, float originY, float width, float height, float scaleX, float scaleY, float rotation)
```

To achieve a rotation around the center of the sprite, `originX` and `originY` should be respectively half of the sprite's width and height.

Comment: how would u gain the rotation from isTouched to follow the players input?

Comment: You can get the touch position by `Input.getX()` and `Input.getY()`, then use some basic trigonometry to find the angle between sprite's and touch position, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970281/java-calculating-the-angle-between-two-points-in-degrees

Comment: the thing id like to rotate is a sprite and the sprite batch for the texture is not applicable to the sprite how do i fix this?

Comment: `Sprite` extends `TextureRegion`, so the above call should work (it's a SpriteBatch's method). Alternatively, you can use Sprite's methods: `sprite.setRotation(float degrees)`, then `sprite.draw(Batch spriteBatch)`.