# How to Rotate a Box Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an image of a box that is 140 pixels in both width and height, and I would like to rotate it along a corner on a tapping gesture or keypress. I am having difficultly in gradually rotating until it reaches the ground again.

[image]

Is there any way that I can reproduce this functionality in which I rotate the sprite along its right corner until it once again reaches the baseline triggered by a single input event? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, guess my comment was deleted. Are you using a Sprite or a Scene2d Image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotate Image Clockwise using LibGDX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445035/rotate-image-clockwise-using-libgdx)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I've tried changing the anchor point and rotating, then Scene2d actions.